How can I save a collection of CultureInfo type using EF Core without adding backing fields?
In a class, I have a collection of type List<CultureInfo> OfficialLanguages. I need to respect domain driven design for this project. I cannot add a backing field of type List<string> officialLanguagesCodes and handle it that way.
When I have a single property like User.Culture, I can handle a conversion like this in my OnModelCreating:
modelBuilder
    .Entity<User>()
    .Property(u => u.Culture)
    .HasConversion(c => c.Name, s => new(s));

How can I achieve something similar for a collection?
I tried the model Builder HasConversion on the collections but did not work:
modelBuilder
    .Entity<Community>()
    .Property(c => c.OfficialLanguages)
    .HasConversion(l => string.Join(',', l), s => s.Split(',', StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries)
    .ToList());


Look at Value conversions

Encapsulation is not the same as DDD. Where in the domain do you need CultureInfo? Wherever you need CultureInfo, isn't it enough to create it there from a language string?

@GertArnold wouldn't this mean I am modifying my models to fit the database and thus breaking ddd? Legitimate question.

There's no relational database that fits all DDD concepts, so "breaking" DDD to be able to store data inevitably happens all the time. But let's stick to the question, if CultureInfo is a domain concept in your case, then maybe it's worth while to do this conversion in the data layer. But even then you may decide to do it not earlier than in the domain model (I'm implying here that the EF class model is not the domain model).

Just store the language string. If you have a lookup list of supported CultureInfo already loaded then your entity or better, a projected view model can provide a getter that looks it up from the available list or composes a new CultureInfo instance. I mean if you have a system that uses colours, it makes sense to store just the ARGB value in the database, not a .Net Color object.
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public string LanguageName { get; set; }

    public CultureInfo? CultureInfo => SupportedCultures
        .FirstOrDefault(x=> x.Name == LanguageName);
}

Where "SupportedCultures" is a static Singleton for the supported languages, handling unsupported strings as you see fit with an exception or a default, etc. (The above just returns #null)
Alternatively:
public CultureInfo? CultureInfo => new CultureInfo(LanguageName);

Handles creating a culture info for the designated language name, trusting the value will always be a supported one, but allowing older unsupported to work without error.
You could put the read-only accessor in the entity itself, however it's really only applicable to UI-based logic and would have to be marked with a [NotMapped] attribute as it isn't something that you would be able to query in a Linq expression. (Which you would use the Language Name for any querying.
Edit: If the ViewModel needs a set of languages then there are a few options. EF Core 8 introduced support for primitive collections automatically in a string using JSON. Alternatively you can use converters in EF Core 6, conversion to/from string with a value converter or manually, or adopt a many-to-many relationship for a "Culture" table (Essentially a table for SupportedCultures consisting of just the Culture.Name as the PK) The advantage of the many-to-many approach is that it does enforce referential integrity at the database level. No row can exist in the main table having a LanguageId (LanguageName) that isn't in the supported cultures table.
Using EFCore's simple collection:
public class SomeEntity
{
    // ...

    // Can be configured to be stored as a simple string in DB using JSON directly translated.
    public ICollection<string> LanguageNames { get; set; } = new [];
 }
    

see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-8.0/whatsnew#primitive-collections for details about primitive collection support. That then just maps across to our view model which does the translation using the static set of CultureInfo.
public class SomeViewModel
{
    public ICollection<string> LanguageNames { get; set; } = new [];

    public IEnumerable<CultureInfo> CultureInfos => SupportedCultures
         .Where(x => LanguageNames.Contains(x.Name));
}

For a more manually serialized embedded set:
public class SomeViewModel
{
    private string? _languageNames;
    // Mapped by EF
    protected string LanguageNames 
    { 
        get => return _languageNames; 
        set
        {
            _languageNames = value;
            CultureInfos = parseCultures(value);
        }
    }
    
    public IEnumerable<CultureInfo>? CultureInfos { get; private set; }

    private IEnumerable<CultureInfo> parseCultures(string languageNames)
    {
        // Split based on how they are stored, or deserialize JSON, etc.
        IEnumerable<string> values = languageNames.Split("|");
        return SupportedCultures.Where(x => values.Contains(x.Name));
    }
}

For a normalized many-to-many you would have a simple Culture entity
public class Culture
{
     [Key]
     public string Name { get; protected set; }
}

Then set up a many-to-many relationship for a Cultures collection on your entity(ies) that reference cultures. Inside your referencing entities you would still project out the culture names to the view model and have the view model translate these into CultureInfo like the above example. I would leave the conversion/mapping at the view-model level because while you certainly can have it in the entity, or use a value converter or extension method to convert a Culture entity to a CultureInfo easily enough, it isn't something "safe" in the entity as it cannot be used in Linq-to-SQL expressions and the like.

But this example is for a single property right? What if the property is a collection of type List?

Yep, several options for handling that. I have expanded the answer to outline a few of them.
